# first_value windowing function in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

I am using pyspark 1.5 getting my data from Hive tables and trying to use windowing functions.

According to [this](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html) there exists an analytic function called `firstValue` that will give me the first non-null value for a given window. I know this exists in Hive but I can not find this in pyspark anywhere.

Is there a way to implement this given that pyspark won't allow UserDefinedAggregateFunctions (UDAFs)?

Comment: See this [link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-9740). 1.6 has this, can we replicate?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Spark >= 2.0**:

`first` takes an optional `ignorenulls` argument which can mimic the behavior of `first_value`:

```
df.select(col("k"), first("v", True).over(w).alias("fv"))
```

**Spark < 2.0**:

Available function is called [`first`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.first) and can be used as follows:

```py
df = sc.parallelize([
    ("a", None), ("a", 1), ("a", -1), ("b", 3)
]).toDF(["k", "v"])

w = Window().partitionBy("k").orderBy("v")

df.select(col("k"), first("v").over(w).alias("fv"))
```

but if you want to ignore nulls you'll have to use Hive UDFs directly:

```py
df.registerTempTable("df")

sqlContext.sql("""
    SELECT k, first_value(v, TRUE) OVER (PARTITION BY k ORDER BY v)
    FROM df""")
```

Comment: Good call on using Hive queries.