# last function with Window orderBy expression not working as expected

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Apache Spark: 3.3.2, Google Dataproc 2.1

```
scala> val orderDF = Seq(("1234","created","2023-09-17 00:00:00"),("1234","updated","2023-09-17 01:00:00")).toDF("orderID","status","eventTimestamp")

scala> orderDF.show(false)
+-------+-------+-------------------+
|orderID|status |eventTimestamp     |
+-------+-------+-------------------+
|1234   |created|2023-09-17 00:00:00|
|1234   |updated|2023-09-17 01:00:00|
+-------+-------+-------------------+

scala> orderDF.select($"orderID",$"status",$"eventTimestamp",last($"status").over(Window.partitionBy($"orderID").orderBy($"eventTimestamp")).alias("latestStatus")).show(false)
+-------+-------+-------------------+------------+
|orderID|status |eventTimestamp     |latestStatus|
+-------+-------+-------------------+------------+
|1234   |created|2023-09-17 00:00:00|created     |
|1234   |updated|2023-09-17 01:00:00|updated     |
+-------+-------+-------------------+------------+

scala> orderDF.select($"orderID",$"status",$"eventTimestamp",first($"status").over(Window.partitionBy($"orderID").orderBy($"eventTimestamp".desc)).alias("latestStatus")).show(false)
+-------+-------+-------------------+------------+
|orderID|status |eventTimestamp     |latestStatus|
+-------+-------+-------------------+------------+
|1234   |updated|2023-09-17 01:00:00|updated     |
|1234   |created|2023-09-17 00:00:00|updated     |
+-------+-------+-------------------+------------+
```

In the above example last function is not honouring the Window orderBy provided. However the first function works as expected. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things should be changed:

### Use `min` and `max` instead of `first` and `last`

[first](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.0/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#first(columnName:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) and [last](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.0/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#last(columnName:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) do not return the first and last element in the sense of the given order but the first and last element that Spark "sees" of the group. The documentation says

> The function is non-deterministic because its results depends on the order of the rows which may be non-deterministic after a shuffle.

Instead of `first` and `last` [min](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.0/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#min(columnName:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) and [max](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.0/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#max(columnName:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) should be preferred.

### Add `rowsBetween` to the window specification when using `orderBy`

When using `orderBy` in the windows specification the default value for the last row is *current* ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47130090/2129801)) so the 'group' for the first row does not contain the second row.

The code should be changed to

```scala
val windowAsc = Window.partitionBy($"orderID")
                      .orderBy($"eventTimestamp")
                      .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)
orderDF.select($"orderID",$"status",$"eventTimestamp",max($"status")
       .over(windowAsc).alias("latestStatus")).show(false)

val windowDesc = Window.partitionBy($"orderID")
                       .orderBy($"eventTimestamp".desc)
                       .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)
orderDF.select($"orderID",$"status",$"eventTimestamp",min($"status")
       .over(windowDesc).alias("latestStatus")).show(false)  }
```

to produce the expected result.

Comment: I did consider using min/max.
1> I was intrigued that first function was returning the correct result. Maybe it was just coincidence that first function worked correctly every time. 
2> Thanks for your inputs on rowsBetween