Last value in a partition, order by a timestamp column PySpark
I need to create a "last_value" which contains the last "value" partitioning by an "id" and ordering by a "created_date".
Example of dataset:



id
created_date
value




123
2023-10-01 08:12:22
Not OK


123
2023-10-02 07:13:14
In Progress


123
2023-10-03 08:52:33
Document request


456
2023-10-01 11:34:01
OK



My desidered output:



id
created_date
value
last_value




123
2023-10-01 08:12:22
Not OK
Document request


123
2023-10-01 07:13:14
In Progress
Document request


123
2023-10-01 08:52:33
Document request
Document request


456
2023-10-01 11:34:01
OK
OK



I tried, without success, this code:
w = Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy('created_date')
 df = df.withColumn('last_value', F.last('value').over(w))
Thank u!

You'd have to use .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing) with the last() function. Implicitly, this value is .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
Further Reading:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-analytic
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/last_value

Referenced documents are from Snowflake, however the concepts remain the same. Hope this helps.
from pyspark.sql.types import TimestampType

data = [
    (123, "2023-10-01 08:12:22", "Not OK"),
    (123, "2023-10-02 07:13:14", "In Progress"),
    (123, "2023-10-03 08:52:33", "Document request"),
    (456, "2023-10-01 11:34:01", "OK"),
]

schema = ["id", "created_date", "value"]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)
df = df.withColumn('created_date', col('created_date').cast(TimestampType()))

df.show()
+---+-------------------+----------------+
| id|       created_date|           value|
+---+-------------------+----------------+
|123|2023-10-01 08:12:22|          Not OK|
|123|2023-10-02 07:13:14|     In Progress|
|123|2023-10-03 08:52:33|Document request|
|456|2023-10-01 11:34:01|              OK|
+---+-------------------+----------------+

from pyspark.sql.functions import last, col
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df = df.withColumn(
    "last_value",
    last("value").over(
        Window.partitionBy("id")
        .orderBy("created_date")
        .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)
    ),
)

df.show()
+---+-------------------+----------------+----------------+
| id|       created_date|           value|      last_value|
+---+-------------------+----------------+----------------+
|123|2023-10-01 08:12:22|          Not OK|Document request|
|123|2023-10-02 07:13:14|     In Progress|Document request|
|123|2023-10-03 08:52:33|Document request|Document request|
|456|2023-10-01 11:34:01|              OK|              OK|
+---+-------------------+----------------+----------------+


ordering it by desc and taking the first value works for me
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (123, "2023-10-01 08:12:22", "Not OK"), 
        (123, "2023-10-02 07:13:14", "In Progress"), 
        (123, "2023-10-03 08:52:33", "Document request"), 
        (456, "2023-10-01 11:34:01", "OK"),
    ],
    ["id", "created_date", "value"]
)

w = Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy(F.desc('created_date'))
df = df.withColumn('last_value', F.first('value').over(w))


Why first function works, while the last not?
Thank u!

you can find more details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43114445/how-to-use-first-and-last-function-in-pyspark
