# Most frequent class by group in PySpark rdd , without converting into Spark Dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I want the most frequent class in each group. 
There can be multiple rows in each group and also there can be multiple classes.
We can ignore the issue of a tie since this python should automatically take the first class.

I tried changing the rdd to spark data frame and then use the code from following link [pyspark: aggregate on the most frequent value in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45634725/pyspark-aggregate-on-the-most-frequent-value-in-a-column?noredirect=1&lq=1)

However I am trying to do it without converting the data into SparkDataframe

Below is the data set

```
Data= sc.parallelize([(1, 'class1', 0.0),
       (1, 'class1', 2.9870435922860854),
       (1, 'class1', 3.1390539564237088),
       (2, 'class1', 1.8147552294243288),
       (2, 'class1', 2.2762141107738643),
       (2, 'class1', 2.3276650040679754),
       (3, 'class1', 2.1916602976063415),
       (3, 'class2', 2.8092745089004265),
       (3, 'class2', 2.962653217205646),
       (4, 'class2', 1.9684050295783773),
       (4, 'class2', 2.6954556024643974),
       (4, 'class1', 2.849277442723792),
       (5, 'class2', 2.42178294501635),
       (5, 'class2', 3.650846798310411),
       (5, 'class1', 4.209012410198228),
       (6, 'class1', 1.942895930291406),
       (6, 'class1', 2.3133629778496676),
       (6, 'class2', 3.0147225096785264),
       (7, 'class1', 1.7185194340256884),
       (7, 'class1', 2.91322741107079),
       (7, 'class1', 3.5767422323347633),
       (8, 'class1', 2.4711392945465893),
       (8, 'class1', 3.436547108084221),
       (8, 'class1', 3.937683211352823),
       (9, 'class1', 3.800013103330196),
       (9, 'class1', 4.632413017908266),
       (9, 'class1', 5.191184050603831),
```

Expected Output

```
  [(1, Class1),(2,Class1),(3,Class2),(4,Class2),(5,Class2),(6,Class1),(7,Class1),(8,Class1),(9,Class1)]
```

Also, I may have multiple classes.

The first element in each row is the group id, the second element is the class, the third element is just distance I don't think that isn't really much of a use.

Comment: A bit much the tie, what does it matter?

Comment: The tie doesn't matter. Thus there is no need to handle it separately.

Comment: May be an idea to award points as per protocol, or, comment otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the RDD solution for pyspark

```
>>> rddMap1 = Data.map(lambda x: (str(x[0])+','+x[1],float(x[2])))
>>> rddMap1.first()
('1,class1', 0.0)
>>> 
>>> rddReduce1 = rddMap1.reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y)
>>> rddReduce1.first()
('1,class1', 6.126097548709794)
>>> 
>>> rddMap2 = rddReduce1.map(lambda x: (int(x[0].split(',')[0]),(x[0].split(',')[1],x[1])))
>>> rddMap2.first()
(1, ('class1', 6.126097548709794))
>>> 
>>> rddReduce2 = rddMap2.reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x if x[1] > y[1] else y)
>>> rddReduce2.first()
(1, ('class1', 6.126097548709794))
>>> 
>>> rddReduce2.map(lambda x: (x[0],x[1][0])).collect()
[(1, 'class1'), (2, 'class1'), (3, 'class2'), (4, 'class2'), (5, 'class2'), (6, 'class1'), (7, 'class1'), (8, 'class1'), (9, 'class1')]
```

Comment: I just saw this and tried this on the above-given data and it works. Now when I am trying this on a much larger same format dataset. I am getting an error in "rddMap1.reduceByKey" function. Any idea why it won't work on a larger data set which a result rdd of some other operation?

Answer (score -1):

```
from operator import add
from operator import itemgetter

data= sc.parallelize([
   (1, 'class1', 0.0),
   (1, 'class1', 2.9870435922860854),
   (1, 'class1', 3.1390539564237088),
   (2, 'class1', 1.8147552294243288),
   (2, 'class1', 2.2762141107738643),
   (2, 'class1', 2.3276650040679754),
   (3, 'class1', 2.1916602976063415),
   (3, 'class1', 2.1916602976063415),
   (3, 'class1', 2.1916602976063415),
   (3, 'class2', 2.8092745089004265),
   (3, 'class2', 2.962653217205646),
   (3, 'class4', 1.9684050295783773),
   (3, 'class4', 2.6954556024643974),
   (3, 'class4', 2.849277442723792),
   (3, 'class4', 2.42178294501635),
   (5, 'class2', 3.650846798310411),
   (5, 'class1', 4.209012410198228),
   (6, 'class1', 1.942895930291406),
   (6, 'class1', 2.3133629778496676),
   (6, 'class2', 3.0147225096785264),
   (7, 'class1', 1.7185194340256884),
   (7, 'class1', 2.91322741107079),
   (7, 'class1', 3.5767422323347633),
   (8, 'class1', 2.4711392945465893)
                 ])

data2 = data.map(lambda x: ((x[0],x[1]), 1)).reduceByKey(add).map(lambda x: ((x[0][0]),(x[0][1],x[1]))).groupByKey().mapValues(list)

data3 = data2.map(lambda (k, l): (k, sorted(l, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)))

data4 = data3.mapValues(lambda x: (x[0]))
```

returns:

```
[(8, ('class1', 1)), (1, ('class1', 3)), (2, ('class1', 3)), (3, ('class4', 4)), (5, ('class1', 1)), (6, ('class1', 2)), (7, ('class1', 3))]
```

Give me Scala any day!

Tie not catered for as stated. Not sure how you would do that anyway and if done what real benefit is not so obvious.

Comment: In the data4 = data3.mapValues(lambda x: (x[0])). I think there needs to be a second argument about  'l' . It was giving me an error TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'l'.

Comment: Also I changed the lambda (k, l) to lambda k,l since lambda function doesnot take multiple arguements in bracket.

Comment: This is the error I am getting."TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'l'  "                                                                                  
 After using your code. Also, the lambda (k, l) function shows a syntax error. which needs to be corrected before executing the code.

Comment: I just ran the script here again - no issues: Spark Jobs
Out[4]: 
[(8, ('class1', 1)),
 (1, ('class1', 3)),
 (2, ('class1', 3)),
 (3, ('class4', 4)),
 (5, ('class1', 1)),
 (6, ('class1', 2)),
 (7, ('class1', 3))]