# PySpark rolling up a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, pyspark

I have the following dataframe-

```
>>> my_df.show(3)
+------------+---------+-------+--------------+
|     user_id|  address|   type|count| country|
+------------+---------+-------+-----+--------+
|      ABC123|  yyy,USA| animal|    2|     USA|
|      ABC123|  xxx,USA| animal|    3|     USA|
|      qwerty|  55A,AUS|  human|    3|     AUS|
|      ABC123|  zzz,RSA| animal|    4|     RSA|
+------------+---------+-------+--------------+
```

How do I roll-up this dataframe to get the following result-

```
>>> new_df.show(3)
+------------+---------+-------+--------------+
|     user_id|  address|   type|count| country|
+------------+---------+-------+-----+--------+
|      qwerty|  55A,AUS|  human|    3|     AUS|
|      ABC123|  xxx,USA| animal|    5|     USA|
+------------+---------+-------+--------------+
```

For a given `user_id`:

1. Get the `country` with the highest sum of counts
2. For the `country` got in step 1, get the `address` with the highest count

I'm guessing I'll have to split `my_df` into 2 different dataframes and get the `country` and `address` separately. But I don't exactly know the syntax for that. Your help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I would try windowing function - ```first``` in ```.select``` and then ```.groupby``` and ```agg``` by user_id and by the 2 columns you want to get from ```first```. This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35142216/first-value-windowing-function-in-pyspark

Comment: I didn't really understand that answer..

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I meant something like this:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import *
>>> from pyspark.sql.window import *
>>> from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

>>> spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('abc').getOrCreate()

>>> data = {"user_id": ["ABC123", "ABC123", "qwerty", "ABC123"], "address": ["yyy,USA", "xxx,USA", "55A,AUS", "zzz,RSA"], "type": ["animal", "animal", "human", "animal"], "count": [2,3,3,4], "country": ["USA", "USA", "AUS", "RSA"]}

>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

>>> df_pyspark = spark.createDataFrame(df)

>>> w = Window().partitionBy("user_id", "country").orderBy((col("count").desc()))

>>> w2 = Window().partitionBy("user_id").orderBy(col("sum_country").desc())

>>> df_pyspark.select("user_id", "address", "type", "count", "country", sum("count").over(w).alias("sum_country")).select("user_id", first("country").over(w2).alias("top_country"), first("address").over(w).alias("top_address"), "country").where(col("top_country")==col("country")).distinct().show()
+-------+-----------+-----------+-------+
|user_id|top_country|top_address|country|
+-------+-----------+-----------+-------+
| qwerty|        AUS|    55A,AUS|    AUS|
| ABC123|        USA|    xxx,USA|    USA|
+-------+-----------+-----------+-------+
```

You may add type, count, etc. depending on which logic you would like to use to do that - you can either do the same as for `top_address` (i.e. `first` function), or you can `groupBy` and `agg`

Comment: this works good. Although, the `df_pyspark.count()` when I added the `type` and `count` columns to it is different from when I did not have those columns. I did `df_pyspark.select("user_id", "address", "type", "count", "country", sum("count").over(w).alias("sum_country")).select("user_id", first("country").over(w2).alias("top_country"), first("address").over(w).alias("top_address"), "country", "type", col("sum_country").alias("count")).where(col("top_country")==col("country")).distinct().show()`. What do I do?

Comment: Also, `type` will always remain the same for a given `user_id`.

Comment: Hm, this should work fine then. So the above, if you replace ```.show()``` with ```.count()``` should return 2, does it show different for you?

Comment: i didn't get you. Btw, i just checked the data - and there seems to be duplicate rows because there's **multiple different counts** for the same combination of a given **user_id, address, type, country**. How did this happen? Should I just do a `groupBy("user_id", "address", "type", "country").sum()` on the final `df_pyspark`?

Comment: Yes, because ```distinct()``` only removes duplicates per row (for all columns), so you can either incorporate ```count``` into windowing function analogically to e.g. ```address``` so: ```first("count").over(w).alias("top_count")```, so make it the same as per the window. Or you can do ```groupBy``` ```agg``` and take e.g. max. from ```count``` as per: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.groupBy